# Mapping set of vectors into given subspaces by rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, rotations

Is it possible to find a set $V=\{V_1,...,V_n\}$  of $m$ dimensional distinct  subspaces $V_i \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ so that 
for any linearly independent subset $X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ there is a rotation that maps each $x_i$ into $V_{\tau(i)}$ where $\tau$ is a permutation.

If that is possible then what is the smallest $m$ so that the answer is affirmative. Does anybody know results of similar kind ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Presumably, you mean a rotation that maps *every element of $X$* into *some element of $V$*

Comment: Yes, I see what you are saying. My bad notation, corrected the question now..

Comment: @JohnHughes (to notify you, too, as you seemed interested) Ok, my intuition was certainly wrong: take two orthogonal planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then given any base $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ we can always rotate it so that the two first vectors are in the first plane, and then by a rotation preserving the first plane make it so that the third vector is in the second plane. So we have a solution for $n=3,m=2$ not even using all the planes we were allowed to. I don't think we'll have a solution for $n=3,m=1$, though.

Answer (score 2):

No. Look at $m = 1$ and $n = 2$. You're asking "is there a pair of lines through the origin in the plane with the property that for any independent 2-element set, some rotation takes the first vector to one line and the second vector to the other."

If there were, there'd be some angle between the two lines, say $\alpha$. Take any two vectors where the angle between them is neither $\alpha$ nor $\pi - \alpha$, and you cannot rotate these to like in the two specified lines, because rotation preserves angles.

My *guess* is that it's not true in any dimensions except $n = 0, 1$. Think about $m = 2$ and $n = 3$. The dihedral angles formed by the planes spanned by 2-element subsets of $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are invariant under rotation; if they don't match the dihedral angles (or their supplements) for the $V_i$, then you cannot find a rotation. I think this argument generalizes to all cases where $m = n - 1$, and it sure looks as if something like Plucker coordinates would suffice to handle cases of other codimensions.

Comment: This is of course the correct answer, and the correct reason. But do you have an elegant proof that it doesn't work for $m<n$ in dimension $n$? I tried a bit and didn't come up with any "beautiful" proofs...

Comment: See my further comments. I'm betting Plucker does the trick; aren't Plucker coordinates invariant under rotations? (I haven't really looked at them for about 30 years...) And how do you make an umlaut outside of LaTeX?

Comment: Mmmh... I saw them in my algebraic geometry course, but I'm rusty, too. However, we could consider the variety of configurations of $n$ distinct $(n-1)$-subspaces, mod it out by the natural action by $SO(n)$ and use a Sard's theorem kind of reasoning to show that a generic configuration of $n$ independent vectors is not in the orbit, in some sense. Not sure how to make this formal, though... Well, +1 meanwhile, but I'm pretty curious now.

Comment: (In fact, I'm betting that it is not possible for any finite number of at most $(n-1)$-dimensional subspaces. And I would also go out on a limb and say that the same is true for a countable number of subspaces. Maybe I'll post it as a separate question.)

Comment: I like the Sard's theorem idea. I think dimension-counting might do it. How many (unit-vector) bases are there with one vector taken from each $V$? The space of such things has dimension $n(m-1)$. But the space of all n-vector bases has dimension $(n-1)^n$. Even if you divide that by $dim(SO(n))$, it's just too darned big (for most $n,m$).

Comment: I agree m=1 doesn't work in any dimension n>1. However I can't see the dihedral angles argument for m=n-1.

Comment: Agreed Otto...but for $m = n = 1$, the claim is correct (but perhaps not very deep). I said that I didn't believe it for any dimensions *except* $n = 0, 1$.

Comment: I think I have a proof (for the $m=n-1$ case). See my answer below.

Comment: Damn! Errata: did some stupid stuff with the dimensions. Not sure it works anymore. You can see it deleted below.

Comment: Those determinants look a lot like Plucker coords. :) I agree that you're close. I like the observation that the $m = n-1$ case is sufficient. How did I not see that? :)

Comment: @Otto: I misread your comment as $m = n = 1$ rather than $m = n - 1$; apologies. And I agree...I don't think that the dihedral argument works for higher $n$ without some tuneup. :(

Comment: John, I thought more about the angle argument. I now tend to agree with you and believe that given any set of subspaces $V$ it might be possible to construct $X$ as a counter example. For case $m=2, n=3$ or higher let's set $V$ as xy-plane, yx-plane and xz-plane.  Given $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Take a rotation that maps $x_1$ to xy-plane and $x_2$ to yz-plane. 
Now consider set of all rotations R that keep  $x_1$ in xy-plane and $x_2$ in yz-plane. R is one-dimensional family of rotations.
But when the angle between $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are close to zero no element of $R$ will map $x_3$ to xz-plane.

Comment: Daniel, I I don't know how to view the deleted answer. No link is showing below.

Comment: @otto I'ts because you don't have enough reputation (points). I've undeleted it so you can see it.

Comment: Daniel, I now can see the proof attempt, thanks. I think the problem is elements of $X$ accumulating near one vector. If that is not the case, say max angle between $x_i$ is bounded below with some value, then it might work for m=n-1.  (For m=n-2  two angles away from zero etc.).   I think...